# Listener on JTextField to detect completion of data entry

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield

We are developing an application in Java Swing.

We have a text field and a combo box. The combo box values should be populated from DB based on the value entered in the text field.

The text field length is 4 characters. So, user can enter any value between 1 to 9999.

Which listener would be used to identify that the user has completed their entry in the text field so that I can populate the combo box?

Comment: A DocumentListener or ActionListener would be first considerations

Answer (score 3):

> ..the user has completed his entry in the text field so that i can populate the combobox.

An `ActionListener`. When the user is done, they hit the enter key and an action event will be fired. But..

> ..user can enter any value between 1 to 9999.

This sounds better suited to a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel` and a `ChangeListener` to register selecting a different number.

Answer (score 1):

Use the textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()

```
  textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //TODO
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   //TODO
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  //TODO
 }
```

Comment: *"This question was answered here..."* if that is true, then the question should closed as a duplicate to said question, unless you intended to expand on the idea presented by the original answer and use it to support you own answer to the OPs question

Comment: hello,, thank you for your suggestion.. but i want the listener to wait until the user completes entering values into the text field.. is there any possibility for the same?